# Python 3 how do I access a sockets clients address?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, client-server

I'm a Python newbe and I'm running a typical example socket server using 'select' on a RPi. In the line:

```
connection, client_address = s.accept()
```

As I understand it 'connection' is a socket id and it gets  placed in the 'inputs' list of the select. I print out the 'client_address' after the 'accept' but then later on when I receive data on that socket I would like access to the client_address info again. In debugging when I receive data on some socket I print out the socket as follows

```
for s in readable:
    print('R='+str(s))
```

I get a line like this:

```
R=<socket.socket fd=9, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.1.21', 50000), raddr=('192.168.1.126', 51961)>
```

How do I access the 'raddr' info?

Comment: Does `s.raddr` not work?

Comment: You can use `vars(s)` to find `s`'s attributes and how to access raddr. Definitely try s.raddr like Jon suggests.

Comment: s.raddr resulted in: AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'raddr'

Comment: Socket objects don't appear to have __dict__attribute:TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

Comment: sname=s.getsocketname() returns error AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'getsocketname'

Comment: Opps. Spelled it wrong. Back in a minute

Comment: The remote address (`raddr`) would be `s.getpeername` (`s.getsockname` is the local address)

Comment: for s in writable:
   print('W='+str(s))
   sname=s.getsockname()
   print(str(sname))
results in: W=<socket.socket fd=9, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.1.21', 50000), raddr=('192.168.1.126', 53754)>
('192.168.1.21', 50000)
W=<socket.socket fd=9, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.1.21', 50000), raddr=('192.168.1.126', 53754)>
('192.168.1.21', 50000)
So I use 's' in both cases but getsockname doesn't return the address I would expect. This is hard to read but I don't know how to format a comment.

Comment: getpeername does indeed work! Thank you all. It's a little confusing that when 's' refers to a client socket getsockname returns the server address and getpeername returns the expected address. Not sure how to give extra credit to Gil.